# Aggregate function error in very simple update query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I would like to update a field in a table [localfields] to be my most recent client (MaxOfClientID) so I can use the client ID in other processes.  When I try

```
UPDATE LocalFields SET LocalFields.Number1 = Max([ClientInfo].[ID]);
```

it gives me the error

"Your query does not include the specified expression 'number1' as part of an aggregate function."

This seems like a simple task, but I've spent hours already trying to figure it out to no avail.  What am I missing?

Comment: So localFields is a table in access.  is Number1 a field within that table and is it of the same data type as clientInfo.id? and lastyl this will set all records in localfields.number1 to the clientinfo.id. is that really what you want or are you missing a where clause?

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Yes, localFields is a Table.  Number1 is a number field and ClientInfo.ID is an autonumber.  There is only one record in LocalFields.  I use it to temporarily hold values when I want to open forms or run other queries based on those values i.e. select a client from a list in a form > place that client id in LocalFields.Number1 > open the form that has stats on that client.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (if, that is, ClientInfo is a different table) :

```
UPDATE LocalFields SET LocalFields.Number1 = SELECT Max([ID]) from ClientInfo
```

Comment: "Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT Max([ID]) from ClientInfo'.